# MySql match get record where columns value near others (under threshold)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, algorithm, select

I have the following coordinates records

[image: table]

what I want is, to get all records where `z1` difference with any other record is less than 4 (threshold)

that means in the above table, the last 2 records have a difference less than 4 then I want to get them in the query.

also if a new record with `z1 = 808` exists, then this record and the record with id 28478 should be returned because they have a difference with less than 4.

is there any way I can achieve this in MySql?

or maybe PHP, without talking so long to do it?

Edit:
here is the data:

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|  id   |  x1   |  x2   |  z1   |  z2   |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| 28478 | -1500 | -1496 |   804 |   808 |
| 29929 | -1500 | -1496 |  1444 |  1448 |
| 30051 | -1500 | -1496 | -1168 | -1164 |
| 30346 | -1500 | -1496 |  -336 |  -332 |
| 28039 | -1496 | -1492 | -1128 | -1124 |
| 28969 | -1496 | -1492 | -1424 | -1420 |
| 29265 | -1496 | -1492 |  -520 |  -516 |
| 29872 | -1496 | -1492 |  1288 |  1292 |
| 30122 | -1496 | -1492 |  -932 |  -928 |
| 30846 | -1496 | -1492 |  1376 |  1204 |
| 30898 | -1496 | -1492 |  1380 |  1384 |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

I tried

```
select *
from coordinates t
where 
    x1 between -1500 and -1500 + 4
  and exists (
        select 1
        from coordinates t1
        where t1.id <> t.id
          and abs(t1.z1 - t.z1) <= 4);
```

but didn't work.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where exists (
    select 1 
    from mytable t1
    where t1.id <> t.id and abs(t1.z1 - t.z1) <= 4
)
```

It might be more efficient not to use `abs()`:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where exists (
    select 1 
    from mytable t1
    where t1.id <> t.id and t1.z1 - t.z1 between -4 and 4
)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=49bf9adde93bc74aca4dde5e634c4a36)** - both queries yield:

```
   id |    x1 |    x2 |   z1 |   z2
----: | ----: | ----: | ---: | ---:
30846 | -1496 | -1492 | 1376 | 1204
30898 | -1496 | -1492 | 1380 | 1384
```

Comment: I tried it but didn't work, I've edited my question and insert the data and the query, could you please check it out?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by *does not work*. I added a fiddle to my answer with your sample data: the queries do return the desired result.

Comment: ok I figured out the issue, I should add `x1 between -1500 and -1500 + 4` in both the query and the subquery, like this:
`select t.*
from coordinates t
where x1 between -1500 and -1500 + 4 and exists (
        select 1
        from coordinates t1
        where x1 between -1500 and -1500 + 4 and t1.id <> t.id and abs(t1.z1 - t.z1) <= 4
    );`

because the provided record was just a part of a lot of records in this table, but yea that works so thank you!